# How to store effective text files in git?

Tags: git

I have configurations for 100 devices stored as CSV files. It is structured as:

```
./Device1/*.csv
./Device2/*.csv
./Device100/*.csv
```

Basically the first row in the csv file for each device are the same. I am wondering how can I optimize the structure of the file system, so the size of the repository does not explode. 
Is it a good idea to have the main branch which has only the csv file and create 100 branches for each device? Will this reduce the size of the git repository?

Answer (score 0):

Git is designed mainly to be a version control system for text based files.  This works in your case, assuming the CSV files have typical text content.  A Git repository contains *all* the files in your project, so a Git repo in your case would contain all 100 CSV files.  Regarding the efficiency of this, Git will compress each file while committing it, so your repo size might not bloat the way you imagine.  Also, if, in a given commit, a certain file has no changes, then Git also may not have to recompress that file and persist it.

Comment: How about having Device1 configurations on the main branch and for all the other devices a fork is created from the main branch? Would this help with respect of space? Is there any drawbacks of having many branches? In that way I also could make use of cloning only a specific branch.

Comment: The thing is, the size of your repo is a function of _all_ the branches, along with each file which each branch contains.  Using branches the way you are suggesting is not standard practice in Git.